# polo 2012 - can you add heated door mirrors

Tags: aftermarket-upgrade

```
Vehicle make
VOLKSWAGEN
Date of first registration
15 June 2012
Year of manufacture
2012
```

Hi

My polo doesn't come standard with heated door mirrors. Is there a way I can get heated mirrors fitted either professional or diy?

Comment: Hi - welcome to the site. I'm afraid "How much will it cost" questions are off-topic here, as they are very location specific and go 'stale' quickly - the rest of your question is fine however, so I've just edited out the off-topic bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to retrofit the electric, heated, folding mirrors from any 2009 to 2016 Polo.  A non-exhaustive list of part numbers would include 6R2 857 507 AC (that's the actual mirror, you'll obviously need left and right), 6R2 959 565 D (that's the wing mirror switch which includes the "heat" option).  You may need some wiring loom too.  The other thing you may have to do is use VCDS / VAGCOM to tell the car it has heated mirrors.

Comment: oh bugger it's a garage of a job then. The motor industry has digitalised everything under the moon. GRRRRR

Comment: Not so, if you find someone with VCDS they can code them in for you.  Check out the Ross Tech website.  There is a social network group called something like VCDS users which is a community of private individuals and independent mechanics which have the software and cable to do the work.